# Mirror image disappears when joining with another object

Tags: node-editor

[image]

[image]

Before joining.

After joining.

The Cross and surroundings are half mirror image. But when I join it to the back wall, the mirror image part is disappearing. 
Please tell me why and how can I solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: the objects will have the same modifiers as the last one you've selected before the ctrl J

Answer (score 2):

Objects are not carrying their modifiers. After joining them, only the main object's modifiers will be valid. If you have a mirror modifier on the cross apply it first, then join them.

Comment: Thanks moonboots and FFeller. I will do that.